# Suffixes of a string that are also prefix of the same string in O(n)

Tags: string, algorithm, prefix, suffix

Recently, I encountered a problem on the HackerEarth platform, the main idea for solving the problem was to find which suffixes of a string are also the same string's prefix in **linear time**(in size of string). For example, in string "abcdzyabc", "abc" is a suffix of the string and it is also its prefix. We need to find all such suffixes in linear time.

Now say I have a boolean array, *isSuffixPrefix?* of size *n* i.e. the length of the string *str*. *isSuffixPrefix?[i]* is **true** if the suffix of string *str* starting at index *i* i.e. suffix *str[i...n-1]* is also a prefix of the same string *str*, it is **false** otherwise. How can we compute this array in **linear time** (if possible)?

An example for string *s* = "**aaa**":

```
isSuffixPrefix?[0] = true    // as suffix s[0..2] = "aaa" is also the prefix of string s
isSuffixPrefix?[1] = true    // as suffix s[1..2] = "aa" is also the prefix of string s
isSuffixPrefix?[2] = true    // as suffix s[2..2] = "a" is also the prefix of string s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is not exactly the prefix function cause the prefix function is defined as an array π of length n, where π[i] is the length of the longest proper prefix of the substring s[0…i] which is also a suffix of this substring ***and not the whole string***
but you can tweak a bit the function to get what you want. because prefix function is from [0..i] you can reverse the word you want and it would give you the array from [n...i] but also you would need to reverse the array itself:

```py
def pi_prefix_suffix(pattern):
    P = list(pattern)
    m = len(pattern)
    a = [0] * m
    k = 0

    for q in range(2, m + 1):
        while k > 0 and P[k] != P[q - 1]:
            k = a[k - 1]
        if P[k] == P[q - 1]:
            k += 1
        a[q - 1] = k

    return a;
def reverse_string(x):
  return x[::-1]
  
print("abcbabacba")
print(reverse_string(pi_prefix_suffix(reverse_string("abcbabacba"))));
```

output:

```
abcbabacba
[1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

one last thing, you said that

> isSuffixPrefix?[2] = true    // as suffix s[2..2] = "a" is also the prefix of string s

but this is not true in the formal way cause suffix and prefix can't be the whole word (especially if the word is one letter), by definition it has to be some part of the word, if you would consider the whole word it means that any prefix is also a suffix of the word. (if you want to consider also the last letter just add 1 on the array cause it always true)

Comment: But I am still not sure how can we tell from this array whether a suffix is also a prefix or not?

Comment: @Hasip Timurtas

Comment: each place represent the longest suffix that also prefix of the whole string, let say the value of 4th place in the array is 2 in my example, it means the longest string is 2 letters from the 4th place which corresponds to abcBAbacBA (as you can see the prefix of babacba is also the suffix of the string by 2 letters). so if you want to know if you have any length of prefix that also a suffix you check the value on that position isn't zero.
if you want to understand how the algorithm itself and what actually suffix and prefix means I recommend to read about kmp algorithm and π function